# mod rewrite , does not show any image or css or url

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options +Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rq.php?var=$1
```

some thing wrong with that rewriterule ,
it does not allow images or css or any file, to be shown 
i need help to set the query like :

```
localhost/foo -> rq.php?var=foo
```

when foo is a name saved at DB table

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow directories and files that exist to not get rewritten. Add these 2 RewriteCond's after `RewriteEngine On` and before the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a more precise match in order to leave out files. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/$ rq.php?var=$1
```

Have a look here for similar discussion:
http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/